# How can I transfer http header to another page?

Tags: php

I would like to know if it is possible to transfer a defined header to another page.  For example in PHP, I want to send http header value to a new page.

I don't know if it's possible.  PHP or JavaScript is fine.

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: You could call a page with a curl call and send a header like that, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Transfer header? may be if you could share the purpose, will explain the question

Comment: It may help to understand what HTTP is and how it works.  http://www.silicon-press.com/briefs/brief.http/brief.pdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Let's say you have some data that you want to send to another file via HTTP, you could do something like I have shown below.

**FirstFile.php**

```
<?php
    $someVar = "SomeValue";
    header("Location: SecondFile.php?someVar=" . $someVar);
?>
```

So, in the above code, you learn how to transmit data to a new file, now to retrieve and utilize that data, you should do the following as I have done.

**SecondFile.php**

```
<?php
    $someVar = $_GET['someVar'];
?>
```

You use the `$_GET` to achieve this. You can know more about this [here](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: I don't think this is what he trying to do.  The question says "HTTP headers" not "GET".

Comment: Yeah, so, does it not look like that he want's to send some variables in the HTTP Header to another page? Perhaps, a flag would be good for this question because the question is itself not very clear.

Comment: well don't answer, just vote to close

Comment: He has accepted this as the answer @Dagon

Comment: @RocketHazmat he has accepted.